# Adding Hyperlinks to Images in a JavaScript Random Images Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a random image generating array and I am hoping to insert hyperlinks associated with each image  but I can't seem to find an answer or solution that works; or that I can understand enough to adapt to my situation/code. I am a javascript novice just trying to learn as much as I can as I go! Thanks in advance to any help, all is appreciated!

JS as follows:

```
var random_images_array = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg'];

    
function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
    path = path || 'img/'; // default path here
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var img = imgAr[ num ];
    var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
    document.write(imgStr); document.close();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="heroImage" style="text-align: center">
        <script type="text/javascript">getRandomImage(random_images_array, 'img/heroImage/')</script>
</div>
```

Comment: please clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve (show the expected HTML result) - you just want to link the image to the actual image file? or... ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the expected html result will be, in fact i don't think there will be a change to the HTML. I just put it there in case everyone knew something I didn't. What I am hoping to do is add a link associated to the image in the array so that the image in #heroImage is clickable and take you to the appropriate page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I think you're trying to accomplish. Note: don't use document.write -- that has very specific uses and this isn't a good one. Rather use the innerHTML property (and there are other ways too). I modified the code so you could see the result in the snippet.

```js
let random_images_array = [{
    img: "https://picsum.photos/200/300?1",
    link: "https://google.com"
  },
  {
    img: "https://picsum.photos/200/300?2",
    link: "https://yahoo.com"
  },
  {
    img: "https://picsum.photos/200/300?3",
    link: "https://loren.picsum.com"
  }
];

function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
  path = path || 'img/'; // default path here
  path = ''; // JUST FOR S.O. TESTING
  let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgAr.length);
  let img = path + imgAr[num].img;
  let imgStr = `<a href='${imgAr[num].link}'><img src="${img}" alt="" border="0" /></a>`;
  document.querySelector('#heroImage').innerHTML = imgStr;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  getRandomImage(random_images_array, 'img/heroImage/')
})
```

```html
<div id="heroImage" style="text-align: center">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @kinglish for your answer: that wasn't quite what I was hoping to do, will be more specific! I'm making a portfolio site, and on load I want a random large image to load (#heroImage) and be clickable to take user to the page for that photos' subject matter. Kind of like an image-based nav menu. The photos and the links need to be specific, stored locally and chosen by me, but the user will get different one every time they reload. I was hoping for ~something~ like this: `var random_images_array = [<a href="#">'img1.jpg'</a>,<a href="#"> 'img2.jpg'</a>, <a href="#">'img3.jpg'</a>];`

Comment: Ok, I updated it. Now it uses an array of objects. Each object has an `img` and a `link`. Is that more along the lines?

Comment: Woohoo! Yes thanks @kinglish that worked mostly! the only thing is I think there is an issue with the path for the image - when I first tried it I got this error message in the console: "file:///F:/WEBSITE/USETHISONEphoto_website-fromhome/img3.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" which led me to believe it was not looking for the image in 'img/heroImage/' but simply in the root folder ... When I placed the images in the root folder it worked perfectly. A minor inconvenience which I can handle, but tried to figure out why 'img/heroImage' folder structure was not working correctly but could not ..?

Comment: remove this line from my code `path = ''; // JUST FOR S.O. TESTING` and hopefully that will do it

Comment: It worked! So cool!! thankyou @kinglish!

Answer (score 0):

picsum answers GETs from `picsum.photos/width/height` by *redirecting* to a random image with the requested dimensions.

In order to have the image and the link match, you must make the picsum GET request and get the redirect URL from the response "Location" header. That's the URL that should be placed in the DOM.

After running the snippet, right-click the image and open it in new tab. Note the same image appears. Using the original GET url as the href will direct user to a new random image.

```js
// super simple promise-returning http request
async function get(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(xmlHttp));
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url);
    xmlHttp.send();
  });
}

async function getRandomImage(width, height) {
  const url = `https://picsum.photos/${width}/${height}`;
  let res = await get(url);

  // this is the important part: we need the redirect url for the image
  const redirectURL = res.responseURL
  const html = `<a href='${redirectURL}' target='_blank'><img src="${redirectURL}" alt=""/></a>`;
  const el = document.querySelector('#heroImage')
  el.innerHTML = html;
}

getRandomImage(200, 300)
```

```html
<div id="heroImage" style="text-align: center">
</div>
```

Notice that we don't need to fool around with a random pick from an array of URLs. picsum does the randomizing on the initial GET.

Comment: Thank you @danh for your answer! but it was not actually a random image I wanted - it was a random pick from a group of images I stored locally, sorry wasn't that clear at first. But cool use of Picsum, this is my first introduction to this site, i like it.

Comment: I may have misdirected you - I used picsum just for illustrative purposes whereas OPs code was for local images

Comment: It's me not reading carefully, Kinglish.  It was a fun exercise to figure out picsum, anyway.